# How to "Reduce request serialization" and increase Google Page Speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

So apparently these two external js files are messing with my Google PageSpeed, it states:

- http://otter.topsy.com/stats.js?etc...
- http://ajax.googleapis.com/.../jquery.min.js

Are both serialized requests (whatever that means?) and gives virtually no explanation or ideas on how to change that fact.

Take a look at this sample Google PageSpeed checker page for jQuery.com as an example: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fjquery.com_2F&mobile=false&rule=AvoidExcessSerialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the total number of requests (thus also reducing serialization) using a JavaScript and CSS bundler.  These tools combine multiple JavaScript files into a single JavaScript file (optionally minifying the files as well), and multiple CSS files into a single CSS file.  This results in fewer HTTP connections from the browser to the server, so there are fewer things to be fetched serially.

ASP.Net MVC 4 has built-in support for this:

http://theshravan.net/bundling-and-minification-support-in-asp-net-mvc-4/

There are a number of solutions for other environments as well such as [Juicer](http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/juicer_a_css_and_javascript_packaging_tool/).

If you cannot bundle all resources (perhaps some come from a CDN while others are served locally), you can use a load manager such as [require.js](http://requirejs.org).

Answer (score 0):

One loads and only then does the other load. Google is telling you to load them asynchronously (you can use some sort of load manager like require.js or head.js).